# Python Logging With FileHandler & dictConfig - Use Environment Variables in "filename"?

Tags: python, json, logging

I'm setting up logging using `dictConfig`. I'm storing the configuration in a json file

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": "True",
    "formatters":{
        "default":{            
            "format": "%(levelname)s : %(asctime)s : %(name)s - Bum holes %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        }
    },
    "handlers":{
        "file":{
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "when": "midnight",
            "interval": 1,
            "formatter": "default",
            "filename": "Nymus\\Logs\\Logs.log"
        }
    },
    "root":{
        "handlers": ["file"]
    }
}
```

Which is then passed to the `logging.config.dictConfig` to be initialized. The reason I'm doing this is to keep my logger configuration in one file and not scattered about. However, I've hit a problem when it comes to the "filename" parameter in the json file. What I want to do is to be able to write something like `"filename": "%APPDATA%\\Nymus\\Logs\\Logs/log`

Is this sort of thing possible? I looked into using the `args` parameter to pass paramters to whatever is listed in "class", but I couldn't get that to work at all.

Comment: Get *env* value and after `json.load(<jsonfile>)` and before `logging.config.dictConfig()` overwrite your filename parameter in your json

Comment: I did that as a workaround, but I was hoping to use this as a self contained config file. I'm still curious if it is possible.